# NoMethodError: undefined method 'admin_users'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to rails so I'm working on the lynda.com Ruby on Rails 5 Essential Training. I got to section 6 the last part titled "**Traverse a rich association**". From the rails console I used the command `section.admin_users` and got

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `admin_users' for #<Section:0x000000033e76c0>.
```

I followed the tutorial and even compared my code to the example files and see no reason I may be getting this error. I have a [github repo](https://github.com/trmccormick/rails_simple_cms) with all the code. Not sure why I get this.

Comment: is `section` an object?  Like, did you query for that?

Comment: yes that is correct they had done section = Section.first it's just pulling it from the database.

Comment: Restarted console after running the last migration?

Comment: I hadn't tried that. I went out and back in and it worked. Thanks

Comment: Good to know that. I saw your code and everything is fine there. The only problem you could have "not restarting the console". :) Happy learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sharvy suggested restarting the console fixed my issue.

Answer (score -3):

Above, you say you queried for this `section.admin_user`

In the section model:

```
class Section < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :page
  has_many :section_edits
  has_many :admin_users, :through => :section_edits

end
```

Section has many admin users.  Try to modify your query to:

```
section = Section.first
section.admin_users
```

This is assuming you have a Section object in the database.

Comment: You down vote me and change your post?  You had like no information up there, what you said you did, you had a bad query.

Comment: @Eric, I think Tracy tried `section.admin_users`, and you can guess that by reading the error.

Comment: He originally had `section.admin_user` this as his query... then he changed the post, which makes my suggestion outdated...

Comment: Which is fine, but why downvote me for trying to help.  The original state of the post had `section.admin_user` as his error, I suggested to update his query to the model relationship